# Manga with a male main character who has a female sprite teaching him Spirit Magic

Tags: story-identification, manga

I think it could of been an Isekai with a male main character who has a female sprite who is teaching him Spirit Magic. The main character comes across a girl in the woods who has escaped from the slavers and has what looks like a burn on one side of her face.

The girl calls out for help and the main character goes to help. After a brief fight with the two slavers they call a bear that they had enslaved to attack the main character, but the girl ends up pushing him out the way and taking the blow and getting captured.

The main character goes to town to track down the the girl at a slavers store, but ends up embarrassing the owner of the store. While the main character is standing in front of the girls cage the Sprite informs him it would cost him around one Gold coin to purchase the girl. Then the slave store owner turns up and demands 20 Gold Coins for the girl for what the main character had done to him out the front of his store. The main character says he will return in one week with the 120 Gold coins to purchase the girl.

Answer (score 2):

Manga Title is: ["Bocchi Tenseiki" or "The Reincarnation Record of Bocchi"](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ghn8cre/bocchi-tenseiki)

> An unemployed, virgin 29-years-old Loner man who has a very deep distrust toward humans was trying to save a woman who was almost raped. He is stabbed in the chest by the assaulter and left to die alone while cursing the humans. When he came to, he realized that he had reincarnated in another world as the second son of a lower noble family where magic and spirit exist as a human baby named Ash Hawkwood.

Comment: You can accept your self-answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].